# How to add a ruler for both x and y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add a ruler to a ggplot plot? I need to see how many mm or cm there is in the plot for the different bars in different scenarios. I want to know how big my output needs to be depending on the number of bars and a great help would be to display mm or cm information for the x and y axis.

Comment: Have you tried using abline() with unit(x , "cm")? (grid package required)

Comment: Can you please promote this into a proper answer, there are many ways to add options to abline and would be nicer not having to guess

Comment: Can you provide some more info what your question is exactly? I know what a ruler is (i think), but why and where do you need it? R-plot functions automatically scale the barplots to fit the graphical window. Could you provide an example to show where it would come in handy?

Comment: I need it as helper to find the width relationship between elements in a plot i.e. the plot is generated dynamically and the number of bins is also dynamic but I want to size the total output width so that the bin size remains constant despite the number of bins. To do this I need a way to see the exact cm or mm within the plot. There are other aspects e.g. legend width but I can handle that ..

Comment: There is no standard ruler available (as far as i know). The plot size (in cm) will depend on what you specify as output: `pdf("plots.pdf", width=6, height=3)` will make a 6:3 inch plot (standard PDFsize is 7:7 inch). So for a ruler one should assume a plot size. But if i understand correctly, the plot (output) size is the thing you would want to vary, to get the right size for your binwidth, right? It is difficult to tell without a reproducable example. Other option: can't you adjust the binwidth depending on the number of bins?